# Find the Taylor expansion of the function $f(z)=z/(z+1)^2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Find the Taylor expansion of the function  $f(z) = \frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$ about $z_0=i$

$f(z) = \frac{1}{(1+z)^2}=\frac{1}{z+1}-\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}$

I know that
$\frac{1}{z+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(z-i)^n}{(1+i)^{n+1}}$,

but I don't know how do $\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}$

Comment: Hint: $\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{1 + z} = -\frac{1}{(z + 1)^{2}}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}=-\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\left(\frac{1}{1+z}\right).
$$

Comment: How to write it, because I can't see it?

Comment: @Niki: What do you mean ? You know that taylor serie of $\frac{1}{1+z}$ arround $z=i$. Using my hint, the series of $\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$ is straightforward.